# Remove 'selected' highlighting of Qt/PySide widget

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyside, qtgui

I'm using a stylesheet to customise the look of my Qt/Pyside buttons. When I open the application, the first button is 'highlighted' with a coloured overlay (it moves through the GUI elements when I use the arrow keys). I want to remove this highlighting. I tried:

```
QPushButton, QPushButton:selected { 
  color: rgb(50, 50, 50); 
  background-color: rgba(188, 188, 188, 50); 
  border: 1px solid rgba(188, 188, 188, 250); 
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

but the overlay doesn't go away. I've also tried the most relevant the pseusostates specified here

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states

instead of ':selected' but with no luck. How can I get rid of this highlighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple workaround you could disable the focus on all elements you don't want to be highlighted:

```
QWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

Comment: YES! That did it. After posting my question, I figured that this would be a better approach but haven't had the time to search for it. This is clearly a better solution, and not a 'workaround' ;)

Comment: not a solution, because with NoFocus, QSpinBox cannot be modified via mouse wheel

Comment: In addition, it is only a workaround rather than a solution, since presentation style should have an ability to control the focus overlay behavior/color, rather than removing the whole focus capabilities from code.